# Should we allow database agnostic 'HowTo' questions?

Tags: discussion

Example: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17982/how-to-copy-complete-structure-of-a-table-without-back-up

The OP was asking how to do something in basically any of 3 RDBMS , and received 3 'correct' answers for each RDBMS.

Should these type of questions be allowed, considering the OP has trouble finding the 'accepted answer'?

Comment: I added a link to this question in the [database-agnostic tag wiki](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/database-agnostic/info).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it should be objective and specific, and anyone should be able to see that the answer fits the question.

If it can be answered one of three ways for each of three database systems, it needs to be asked once for each database system. Too many well answered questions is never a problem. Too many half-baked questions is a problem, regardless of the quality of the answers.

Comment: +1 I agree - [tag:database-agnostic] shouldn't be used when there are different correct answers for different platforms. A question like "Generally speaking, what effect does RAID level have on database performance" is an example of a question that I think would pass.

Comment: Agreed - and commented as such on the question in question. Hmm, always wanted to say "the question in question" and that's the first time it's ever come up.

Comment: So is it appropriate that it is now three new questions?

Comment: +1 - I think it's also worth noting that if the question is simple enough to be agnostic ("How do I get all the records from tableA that don't match TableB?") then it should potentially be on SO instead of DBA.  If you need a database expert then you need to know the RDBMS.

Comment: @JNK I think that might be a worthy 'answer' to see what others think of that solution.

Comment: @JHFB yes, that's what we're getting at.